# How are the words "atheist", "non-religious" and "rational thinker" perceived differently in the U.S.?

Tags: atheism, rationalism

*Disclaimer: my question is not technically about philosophical concepts but rather about their perception in American culture.*

I listened to a couple of interviews with Neil deGrasse Tyson, an American astrophysicist and science communicator, he said he prefers to identify as a "rational thinker" or a scientist rather than an "atheist" even though his views technically align with atheism.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2itlUlD10M

He argued that the term atheist carries more negative political and social connotations in the U.S. compared to simply saying one is a scientist focused on evidence.

Do you agree there is a notable difference in how these terms are perceived culturally in the U.S., despite referring to similar approaches to knowledge? Does "atheist" unfairly imply a confrontational stance for many Americans while "rational thinker" comes across as more neutral?

Comment: I don't like to call myself to be a person who thinks this is the answer to this question. I prefer to call myself the clear-thinking, intelligent, honest, and attractive person with the correct answer.

Comment: Do you think he avoids this word for PR reasons?

Comment: I think if such a person actually wanted a word to describe a lack of theism without the non-definitional baggage attached to the atheist label, he would describe himself as a *nonbeliever* or just a *person who does not believe in gods*. Calling yourself a "rational thinker" is just giving yourself a complement, and contains no information about your belief in gods.

Comment: "Atheist" does not refer to an approach to knowledge, an *epistemological* matter, it is an *ontological* position on existence of gods. "Rational thinker focused on evidence" is a mouthful for "simply saying", and cannot serve as a substitute on substance. Agnostics and even theists can be that. But the negative connotation in US is real, see [2014 survey](https://academic.oup.com/sf/article-abstract/95/2/607/2452916) where 40% disapproved of "non-religion", and [New Yorker piece](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2018/10/29/why-are-americans-still-uncomfortable-with-atheism).

Comment: I personally avoid *atheist* as a descriptor because there's a cultural group that self-describes as atheist which subscribes to the idea that religion is not just incorrect but *bad*. Since that is a meaning separate from *lack of belief in gods*, I prefer to use a different word  or phrase to represent *lack of belief in gods* in order to be more clear. I don't particularly care about whether people approve or disapprove. If people hated Koreans, would you call them East Yellow Sea Peninuslans?

Comment: I can't comment on American culture but Tyson's points are great.  "Atheism" does *not* just mean "gods do not exist" but is a cultural signifier for a package of various positions and canons, and this cultural position is parasitic on the same thing in "Christianity" in the west.  One can reject all operative working attempts to define theologies and still not be an Atheist, whether simply through a refusal to culturally engage or in that one can also reject the working Atheist theologies that negatively orient themselves in the Christian traditions they're embedded in.

Comment: @DavidGudeman that's a good guess from the out of context quote (assuming it's a quote - I don't think he says it in the linked video) and the framing of the OP. But the linked video is Tyson going on a 9-minute rant about how self-described atheists often think their ontological commitments make them intellectually superior and how he thinks that that makes them twits. So I doubt that he was actually trying to conflate *Rational Thinker* with *Atheist*.

Comment: ...linked video also provides good evidence for why one shouldn't care what scientists say about things outside of their field, like when astrophysicists go off the cuff about the history of phrases.

Comment: @gs, thanks for the correction. I went off half-cocked on that comment. Now, having watched the video, I'm deleting the comment.

Comment: It's an example of how words become tainted and can't be used neutrally after that.

Comment: I agree that "atheism" has a negative connotation in the US. But the problem with "rational" and "scientist" (and "bright") as an alternative label for atheist is that you'd be baking in an additional claim: that theists are irrational, non-scientists or not bright. I've made the case a few times that theism is irrational and unscientific. But that doesn't mean theists are in general irrational, non-scientists or not bright. "Agnostic" is a more fitting alternative, although you can be an agnostic theist, too. "Skeptic" has become somewhat synonymous with (a particular corner of) atheism.

Comment: Well, people like Dawkins, Lawrence Krauss, Hitchens.. Harari I guess didn;t shy from the word atheist. Some of them are Brits though and Harari is from Israel. I still have an opinion that negativity goes back to XX century politics. Commies, godless atheists, all that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While things are changing, we atheists as a demographic have seen our ranks become more vocal, and non-affiliated thinkers grow. Among philosophers, if [PhilPapers](https://philpapers.org/surveys/linear_most_with.pl?A=background%3Aaffil%3Aregion%3AUnited%20States) is to believed, atheism is the preponderance of views:

> God:theism    0.058
> atheism/theism
> United States
> 72.2%   (404/559)
> 19.4%   (109/559)
> not United States
> 76.5%   (274/358)
> 14.2%   (51/358)
> Response pairs: 917   p-value: 0.079

Which differs radically from the general population [US is known for its religiosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religiosity#Surveys_in_the_United_States). From WP:

> According to a Pew study in 2009, only 5% of the total US population did not have a belief in a god. Out of all those without a belief in a god, only 24% self-identified as "atheist", while 15% self-identified as "agnostic", 35% self-identified as "nothing in particular", and 24% identified with a religious tradition.[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_philosophy)

Among scientists who choose to exercise their philosophical thinking skills on science and religion, the story is much the same with philosophers. According to [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/28478):

> Research on this topic began with the eminent US psychologist James H. Leuba and his landmark survey of 1914. He found that 58% of 1,000 randomly selected US scientists expressed disbelief or doubt in the existence of God, and that this figure rose to near 70% among the 400 “greater” scientists within his sample1. Leuba repeated his survey in somewhat different form 20 years later, and found that these percentages had increased to 67 and 85, respectively.

Dawkins purports that the rate of atheism among members of the NAS, IIRC, is 96%, and [work across the pond seems to be consistent with the US](https://evolution-outreach.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1936-6434-6-33) for this class of intellectuals.

US political sentiment about the US as a God-fearing nation was strongly shifted against "godless Communists" during the Cold War when language like "Under God" was added to our Pledge of Allegiance, and there's a growing threat to political freedom with the rise of [Christian white nationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_nationalism), which is considered the largest source of terrorist threat by Federal LEOs. The US certainly isn't ready for an atheist President.

On account of a steady stigma of atheists, agnostics, and freethinkers, there have been efforts to rebrand as [Brights](http://www.the-brights.net/), notably endorsed by Daniel Dennett, one of the four big [New Atheists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Atheism) (along with Harris, Hitchens, and Dawkins).

In the philosophical world, there is push back on atheist gains and contemporary philosophy that bleeds into post-modernism by philosophers like [Peter Kreeft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Kreeft). He's recently put together what constitutes a metaphilosophically loaded pedagogy in the form of his work [*Socrates' Children* (Federalist.com)](https://thefederalist.com/2023/08/11/peter-kreeft-is-making-philosophy-great-again/) which appeals to political conservatives because it fundamentally devalues [analytical philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_philosophy) as a metaphilosophical discipline. You'll frequently here conservatives bandy the phrase Marxist leftists with a broad brush attacking university professors including those who advocate atheism.

Philosophically, atheists are frequently perceived as enemies of the Christian extremist movement to obliterate the [wall between church and state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_church_and_state) that Jefferson advocated, and various forms of philosophical creationism have waged legal campaigns to be considered forms of science so that public school can teach religious views, most notably under the banner of [intelligent design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_design).

So, give our unique history here in the US, we have a highly religious population which has always payed homage to freedom of and from religion. On the reactionary side, thinkers who advocate a Christian state, often parodied as the American Taliban, have a deep dislike for atheism and freedom of and from religion. And on the radical side, you have militant atheists, generally intellectuals and professors, who are rejoicing at the continuing loss of membership of religious institutions. Most people in the US are friendly to religion, and tolerant, but prefer to think in terms of God, angels, and supernatural thinking the specifics of which [Pew claims are accurate to be found here](https://www.pewresearch.org/religion/2008/06/01/u-s-religious-landscape-survey-religious-beliefs-and-practices/). From Pew:

> A major survey by the Pew Forum on Religion & Public Life finds that most Americans have a non-dogmatic approach to faith. A strong majority of those who are affiliated with a religion, including majorities of nearly every religious tradition, do not believe their religion is the only way to salvation. And almost the same number believes that there is more than one true way to interpret the teachings of their religion. This openness to a range of religious viewpoints is in line with the great diversity of religious affiliation, belief and practice that exists in the United States, as documented in a survey of more than 35,000 Americans that comprehensively examines the country’s religious landscape.

Comment: Do you think that one of the reasons of dislikes towards the "atheist" concept is that it gives political connotations with communist regimes of 20-th century, especially among middle-aged and elderly people?

Comment: Not today. The existential threat of communism is not in the memories of our population anymore. It's history. Today, the greatest unease with atheism swirls with a legacy of anti-atheist claims. One of the most popular ones I hear is that an atheist is immoral because without a God, there can be no morality. Another trope is that atheists like to oppress religious freedom.

Comment: Oppression quickly spreads like a cancer. It is self-defeating. But, cancer is not particularly smart.